Why isn't my chunk loading and unloading function working
Here's my code for chunk loading, unloading, the update world function, and voxel stuff
void generateVoxels(Chunk *chunk) {
    chunk -> voxels = (Voxel *)malloc(sizeof(Voxel) * CHUNK_SIZE * CHUNK_SIZE);

    int colorRand = 5;

    for(int i = 0; i < CHUNK_SIZE; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < CHUNK_SIZE; j++) {
            chunk -> voxels[i * CHUNK_SIZE + j].position[0] = chunk -> position[0] + j;
            chunk -> voxels[i * CHUNK_SIZE + j].position[1] = chunk -> position[1] + i;
            chunk -> voxels[i * CHUNK_SIZE + j].material = MaterialList[rand() % 2];
            for(int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
                chunk -> voxels[i * CHUNK_SIZE + j].material.color[k] += rand() % (colorRand * 2 + 1) - colorRand;
            }
        }
    }
}

void generateChunk(Chunk *chunk, Vector chunkPosition) {

    chunk -> position[0] = chunkPosition[0];
    chunk -> position[1] = chunkPosition[1];
    
    generateVoxels(chunk);
}

Chunk *loadChunk(FILE *file, Vector chunkPosition) {
    Chunk *chunk = (Chunk *) malloc(sizeof(Chunk) + sizeof(Voxel) * CHUNK_SIZE * CHUNK_SIZE);

    if(file == NULL) {
        generateChunk(chunk, chunkPosition);
    } else {
        if (fread(chunk -> position, sizeof(Vector), 1, file) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error reading position from file\n");
        }
        if (fread(chunk -> voxels, sizeof(Voxel), CHUNK_SIZE * CHUNK_SIZE, file) != CHUNK_SIZE * CHUNK_SIZE) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error reading voxel data from file\n");
        }
    }

    return chunk;
}

void unloadChunk(FILE *file, Chunk *chunk) {

    if (fwrite(chunk -> position, sizeof(Vector), 1, file) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error writing position to file\n");
    }

    if (fwrite(chunk -> voxels, sizeof(Voxel), CHUNK_SIZE * CHUNK_SIZE, file) != CHUNK_SIZE * CHUNK_SIZE) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error writing voxel data to file\n");
    }

    fclose(file);
    if (fclose(file) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error closing file\n");
    }

    free(chunk);
}

void drawVoxel(Voxel voxel, Vector offset) {
    SDL_Rect voxelRect = {(int) (SCREEN_WIDTH / 2 - GAME_WIDTH / 2 ) + (int) voxel.position[0] + offset[0], (int) voxel.position[1] + offset[1], VOXEL_SIZE + 1 + offset[0], VOXEL_SIZE + 1 + offset[1]};
    setDrawColor(voxel.material.color);
    SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &voxelRect);
}

void updateWorld() {
    Vector positionChange;
    positionChange[0] = PLAYER_DEFAULT_POS[0] - player -> position[0];
    positionChange[1] = PLAYER_DEFAULT_POS[1] - player -> position[1];

    for(int i = -1; i < 1; i++) {
        for(int j = -1; j < 1; j++) {
            loadedChunks[(i + 1) * 3 + j + 1][0] = player -> position[0] + j * CHUNK_SIZE;
            loadedChunks[(i + 1) * 3 + j + 1][1] = player -> position[1] + i * CHUNK_SIZE;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {

        loadedChunks[i][0] = roundf(loadedChunks[i][0] / CHUNK_SIZE) * CHUNK_SIZE;
        loadedChunks[i][1] = roundf(loadedChunks[i][1] / CHUNK_SIZE) * CHUNK_SIZE;

        char *fileName = malloc(strlen(CHUNK_FILE) + 6 + sizeof(loadedChunks[i][0]) + sizeof(loadedChunks[i][1]));
        sprintf(fileName, "%s/x%dy%d", CHUNK_FILE, (int)loadedChunks[i][0], (int)loadedChunks[i][1]);
        FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "rb+");

        Chunk *chunk = loadChunk(file, loadedChunks[i]);

        if (chunk != NULL) {
            for (int j = 0; j < CHUNK_SIZE * CHUNK_SIZE; j++) {
                drawVoxel(chunk->voxels[j], positionChange);
            }

            unloadChunk(file, chunk);
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error loading chunk\n");
        }

        free(fileName);
    }
}

So I get 9 spots around the player and open the files of the closest chunks, if they're empty it generates chunk and the voxels in them and if it has stuff in the file then it'll load it and then it unloads all the chunks.
I've been messing around with the file reading and writing and that might be the problem since I have a terrible grasp on that stuff.

Oh man this is hard to read... The -> operator is tightly-coupled, so please do not put whitespace around it. Nobody does this.

It's unclear what "the problem" is because you have not described what actually happens when you run your program. Having a look through your code, the allocation of the fileName string's memory is highly suspicious. No idea what size values you're using for your addresses, but using sizeof(int) to determine the number of characters required to represent a value in base 10 is just wrong. Don't be stingey -- just use a buffer larger than you need.

The loadChunk function fails to allocate memory for the voxels. Well, it does, but it's not the same as how generateVoxels does it. So you're gonna have a hard time cleaning up that memory. What I can say for sure is that chunk->voxels is uninitialized when you're reading from a file, so you will certainly have problems there. Could you perhaps familiarize yourself with your debugger? It's a powerful tool that will let you inspect your program, identify and solve issues like this with ease.

How would you fix this, I'm confused why my allocation doesn't work.

The simplest fix is to only allocate sizeof(Chunk) for the chunk structure's memory, and then allocate memory for the voxels separately (like you're already doing in generateVoxels). A beginner should avoid trying to be clever about storing multiple things in a single allocation (like it appears you're trying to do in loadChunk) without a proper understanding of memory alignment. I would suggest that you don't allocate the voxels dynamically at all: CHUNK_SIZE is obviously a constant, so just define the voxels field as Voxel voxels[CHUNK_SIZE][CHUNK_SIZE];

I tried that originally but there was some error that I could only fix by making it #define CHUNK_SIZE instead of const int CHUNK_SIZE and I don't know why

Unlikely anybody will tell you definitively without seeing the code and the error. Anyway, I'm guessing everything is clarified and you've now fixed the program.
